# Outlook 365 (2016) does not send all attachments, only one attachments gets sent

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange-2010

I have a user who updated to the newest build of Office 365 Build 8431.2242 Click-to-Run. This build (frankly, anything after Build 16.0.6965.2117) is having issues sending more than 1 attachment.

We are using Exchange 2010 SP3 Rollup 20 and reviewing the configuration, there are no attachment limitations that would affect emails in this way.

This issue is not present in the previous Build 6965.2117, in this Build attachments send just fine.

The issue doesn't seem to be on the server side as OWA works fine as well.

1. I have tried installing the 32-Bit and 64-Bit versions and both do
   the same.
2. I did try using IMAP and that actually worked just fine but if
   multiple users are going to upgrade, it would be really inconvenient
   migrating everyone to IMAP from Exchange.
3. I removed Add-Ins
4. I removed/disabled the Anti-Virus
5. Recreated the Outlook Profile
6. Tried in Safe Mode
7. Contacted Microsoft support but they only did typical troubleshooting like reinstalling Office and running the Fix-It tool. Steps that i already took...

This issue has been going on for 2 years now and build after build this issue has not gone away. I do not know what else i could possibly try but the only "fix" that i get from Microsoft and other forums is to roll back to the previous build (which is my users are running) but i don't think it is very good to be running on such an old version of office.

Any ideas why I'm having attachment issues past Office Build 16.0.6965.2117?

Comment: Does this issue occur to other Exchange accounts such as an outlook.com account?

Comment: Hmm. Not sure. I have my own exchange account that I can try to setup and make a random Outlook account just for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have decided to just go ahead and upgrade/migrate to Exchange 2016. Nothing seems to be working.